# Openmp call subroutine in parallel region and omp do

Tags: fortran, openmp

I try to call a subroutine which contains a omp do in the main program parallel region omp do.

The fake code like

```
program main
double precision, dimension(0:8,0:8):: a,b,c,temp,final
integer:: i,j,k
integer:: nx=10
integer:: ny=10

a=reshape((/ 1 ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   &
-4  ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   2   ,   2   ,   2   ,   2   ,   &
4   ,   -2  ,   -2  ,   -2  ,   -2  ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   1   ,   &
0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   -1  ,   0   ,   1   ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   1   ,   &
0   ,   -2  ,   0   ,   2   ,   0   ,   1   ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   1   ,   &
0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   -1  ,   1   ,   1   ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   &
0   ,   0   ,   -2  ,   0   ,   2   ,   1   ,   1   ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   &
0   ,   1   ,   -1  ,   1   ,   -1  ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   -1  ,   1   ,   -1  /),shape(a))



b=1.d0/36.d0 * reshape  ((/ 4 ,   -4  ,   4   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
                4   ,   -1  ,   -2  ,   6   ,   -6  ,   0   ,   0   ,   9   ,   0   ,   &
                4   ,   -1  ,   -2  ,   0   ,   0   ,   6   ,   -6  ,   -9  ,   0   ,   &
                4   ,   -1  ,   -2  ,   -6  ,   6   ,   0   ,   0   ,   9   ,   0   ,   &
                4   ,   -1  ,   -2  ,   0   ,   0   ,   -6  ,   6   ,   -9  ,   0   ,   &
                4   ,   2   ,   1   ,   6   ,   3   ,   6   ,   3   ,   0   ,   9   ,   &
                4   ,   2   ,   1   ,   -6  ,   -3  ,   6   ,   3   ,   0   ,   -9  ,   &
                4   ,   2   ,   1   ,   -6  ,   -3  ,   -6  ,   -3  ,   0   ,   9   ,   &
                4   ,   2   ,   1   ,   6   ,   3   ,   -6  ,   -3  ,   0   ,   -9  /),shape(b))



c=reshape((/ 1 ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1   ,   0   ,   &
    0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   1  /),shape(c))

    !$omp parallel
!$omp do
do j=0,ny
do i=0,nx
c(6,6)=i
c(7,7)=i
call muti(a,b,temp)
call muti(temp,c,final)
enddo
enddo
!$omp enddo
!$omp end parallel



end program

subroutine muti(m1,m2,m3)
double precision,dimension(0:8,0:8)::m1,m2,m3,tmp
integer::i,j,k

!$omp do
do j=0,8
    do i=0,8
        tmp(i,j)=0.d0
        do k=0,8
            tmp(i,j)=tmp(i,j)+m1(k,j)*m2(i,k)
        enddo
        m3(i,j)=tmp(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
!$omp enddo
endsubroutine
```

The subroutine calculates matrix multiplication, however I cannot get right result. My problem is not something about how to coding this program, I am confused about how to write the code like this which I need to call the subroutine in another parallel. I read some problems relative to this, still confused. Thanks!

I write the code, the main idea for this is that calculate three matrix multiplication for every (i,j) points. The code behavior very slow, and result is not correct.

Comment: Can you please, please, please, please, *please*, please include a **complete code** and **correct results**. I have no idea what these should be as I can't work out what you expect the nested `!$omp do` constructs to do.

Comment: Hi, I update the code, and some description.

Comment: You still have not told me what the correct results are. Without those I can not help you.